# Is it possible to use two versions of a file in Gitlab at the same time on Production?

Tags: gitlab

I have an application on Production that runs on v2.0 . There is also a set of users who are still using v1.0 of the application on Production. I have a file in Gitlab that the application uses say app_code.sh , that has new code which is required for application with v2.0. But for application with v1.0, the old app_code.sh needs to be used.

My question is, is there a way in Gitlab to allow two versions of the same file to be used on Production. I have checked Tagging/Release feature but they dont meet my requirement.

Note that keeping separate folders for each version of the application will require lot of code changes in the application and also creates separate sets of files in Gitlab , which is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a single script with a single name (`app_code.sh` for example) with a specific version installed on different hosts in production you could pack your code and sending to a repository system which is compliant with your linux/unix distribution in production (yum/`.rpm`, apt/`.deb` or event `.tar.gz`, etc).

The packaging of your sources could be triggered by a gitlab-ci pipeline during the merge of your features branches in the master branch.

If you want to have both versions of a same script at the same time on the same server with different names in the server, it's also possible to play with a gitlab-ci pipeline or other way to deliver your code in production. But in that case, I think it's more relevant to consider to maintain two scripts in your master branch and deliver them in the same package.